# Apple documentation incorrect about MKMapView -regionThatFits:?

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

In the Apple documentation for the `-regionThatFits:` method of the MKMapView, it says that this will return a new region centered on the same point as the region that's passed in, only with the regions bounds corrected for the iPhone screen aspect ratio.  This seems to be incorrect in implementation...before the call to this method, my region shows up as:

```
$5 = {
  center = {
    latitude = 37.322898864746094, 
    longitude = -122.03209686279297
  }, 
  span = {
    latitudeDelta = 14.278411865234375, 
    longitudeDelta = 1.5202401876449585
  }
}
```

..however, after the call to this method, I end up with:

```
$6 = {
  center = {
    latitude = 36.973427342552824, 
    longitude = -122.03209686279297
  }, 
  span = {
    latitudeDelta = 14.521333317196799, 
    longitudeDelta = 14.0625
  }
}
```

This is quite a big difference on the map - this translates to the distance between Cupertino, CA and Santa Cruz, CA.  Anyone else experience this discrepancy?

Comment: Oh, and here's the link for the documentation piece:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW5

Comment: It would really help if you also provided the region that you passed into -regionThatFits:.

Comment: Jeff, sorry.  Specifically, the region I passed into -regionThatFits: is the first code block above.  The region that -regionThatFits: subsequently spits out is the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it's a rounding issue since you used a large latitudeDelta. To make sure, your center is never altered, you could set the adjusted region first, then re-set the center to the old value by using the `centerCoordinate` property.